# Do we want a data.meta.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, per-site-meta

Unfortunately, the data SE doesn't have any meta site.

It could be a very useful feature, people could share their tips and experiences about the site.

Comment: I think meta.SE is good enough for now, no?

Comment: @Mithrandir In theory, yes. In practive, I never met any longer or interesting discussion about the data SE, which would surely happen on a site dedicated to it.

Comment: @Servy  ...why? After the move, which just happened, Meta sites are site.meta, which would probably apply to SEDE if it got it's own.

Comment: @Mithrandir Currently, there is *no* meta.data.stackexchange.com, thus there is nothing to simply move there.

Comment: I know; I wanted to know why @Servy rolled back my edit that switched the proposed meta site from meta.data to data.meta to match other per-site metas.

Comment: @Mithrandir I don't know, I see the meta moves unimportant from this question, but an important won battle in the long-standing war of the SE with the https support, thus I am happy on it. Anyways the question is, if we would want to have a community around data SE, analyzing it and playing on it.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think this is necessary, but we'd likely block it for technical reasons, since it would be a new variant of a child meta breaking over a thousand assumptions about parents in our code.

The only such special casing in place now is https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/, which is already a massive pain and tech debt factor. In fact, it's causing pain with the HTTPS move right now, since I can't move it the same way as everything else.

Comment: Maybe the meta site adaption to different parents could have a separated place in the code base? I suggest a solution where the meta sites are essentially main sites + extended with some synchronisation methods.

Comment: @peterh You do know it's not _actually_ that simple of a change to make, right?

Comment: @Emrakul Yes, I know very well that actually *do* a change is much more large work as imagine it. :-) It was only a suggestion...

Answer (score 8):

Meta Stack Exchange is already the meta for questions about SEDE. Adding a new meta doesn't solve problems, it only adds problems.

The site will have an extremely low traffic, making it prone to spam, low quality posts, etc.

Your proposed topic:

> people could share their tips and experiences about the site.

That is generally not what you'd want on a meta site. Chat is good for sharing experiences.

Comment: *"Meta Stack Exchange is already the meta for questions about SEDE. Adding a new meta doesn't solve problems, it only adds problems."* <- On this reason, all the meta sites should be closed. It is obviously an argumentation mistake. "people could share their tips and experiences about the site." It is definitely the purpose of a meta site.

Comment: No. It is a Q/A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Yes, meta sites are for questions/answers about their main site. Another false argument.

Comment: Then redefine or clarify your proposed topic