# Area 51 - Insecure connection issue when click a link

Tags: bug, area-51, ssl, footer

**UPDATE:**

Since Area 51 is not supporting SSL yet. But the Area 51 link in the **footer** of Meta Stack Exchange site and in the **Your Communities** dropdown list contains `https://`, clicked from there it caused the insecure connection issue.

[image: Area 51 footer]

---

**Actual post**

When I click the [**Minimum Activity Requirements for Area 51**](https://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51) link in the bottom of the [Area 51 main page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), I received the insecure connection issue.

[image: Area 51 main page]

**In Google Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

In plain text:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from discuss.area51.stackexchange.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

**In Mozilla Firefox:**

[image: Firefox]

In plain text:

> Your connection is not secure
>
> The owner of discuss.area51.stackexchange.com has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

Comment: Area51 does not support SSL yet..

Comment: @Floern: Yeah, noticed. I'm trying to identify, from which link I get the `https://` for the Area 51.

Comment: The actual bug here is the https links to Area 51 which should be changed back to http links, especially in the footer which is the most visible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Hope the `https` link is based on the site from where we are seeing. From Stack Overflow footer, it is still `http` only

Comment: Good point, the link is indeed relative (`//area51.stackexchange.com/`). So it should be changed to absolute link.

Comment: This appears to be fixed now. Area 51 is now also on HTTPS, and any old links to discuss.area51.stackexchange.com should now be fixed to point to area51.meta.stackexchange.com. If you still observe problems, you should probably post a new bug report about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the [`http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) is redirecting to [`https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/`](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/).

So the link mentioned in the post is now redirecting to [`https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51`](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51), it didn't throw the insecure error.

So the issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, you're attempting to use https to access it. However, Area 51 doesn't have https yet. From the [https announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time):

> Area 51, Chat, and stackexchange.com (the main site) have a separate set of concerns and code we'll address after Q&A. The list also isn't necessarily in order. While we're testing #6, Samo and I will be working on #11 at the same time.

Also, discuss.area51 is a bit of a trouble maker:

> The only such special casing in place now is https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/, which is already a massive pain and tech debt factor. In fact, it's causing pain with the HTTPS move right now, since I can't move it the same way as everything else.
>   <sub>[(source)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292455/do-we-want-a-data-meta-stackexchange-com)</sub>